# Toshiba Satellite l670-19e seems to be dead. Only a flashing white light on the case — the battery light — is the only sign of life

Tags: laptop, bios, motherboard, power-supply, battery

Initially the laptop worked fine. Windows 10 loaded; and I reached the login screen. I - several times - restarted the computer attempting to create or change the admin account so I can login to the user account - I don't know the password. After restarting several times the computer began to die (it wasn't turning on when the power button was pressed); it turned on occasionally but eventually not at all.

Some research led me to do the following: Take battery and charger out and press power button for 60 seconds then try to turn on; failing that, do the same but then put the battery in and try to turn on, if that fails do the same but then put the charger in without the battery, and try to turn on. All of this failed. My research then led me to opening the laptop to reboot the bios CMOS battery. I think I eventually identified the CMOS battery but it seems to be an unusual type. It isn't a button battery one can remove and put back in, and it isn't attached to any cables. I'll post an image of one very similar:

[image]

The 'thing' on the mother board looks almost exactly like the 'thing' in the picture, although the edges are more smooth on the physical one, and it is a little smaller than a 5 pence piece (UK).

So that is that. I assume it's either a faulty battery, or cable, or a bios issue. I changed the fuse in the plug but that didn't help.

I would appreciate some help with this.

Comment: Do you have access to a multimeter to verify that the charger is working?

Comment: I may do. I'll check. If I don't, what else could I try?

Comment: That is impossible to answer without knowing what you have access to. The problem sounds a lot like no power, so the charger should be the first and easiest thing to test. Be creative. Use a H7 car lamp, a bike lamp or any other incandescent lamp running on 12V. You could go to any repair shop or electrician to let them test the charger for a dollar into the tip jar.